# Square of an ideal, tensor and quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a ring and two ideals $I\subseteq J$. Is this true that $J/I\otimes_AA/J\cong\bar{J}/\bar{J}^2$ where $\bar{J}:=J/I$.

When things get together, I am confused..

Comment: Let $A$ be a commutative ring, $I\subseteq A$ and ideal and $M$ an $A$-module. Then,
$$
M\otimes_A A/I \cong M/IM.
$$
You can find a proof of this result in Dummit and Foote, for example.

Comment: Thank you. I was just not very sure $J.J/I=(J/I)^2$...

Answer (score 1):

From user347489's helpful comment, you can find the result on page 370 in Dummit and Foote.

And taking $N=J/I$, we get $J/I\otimes_AA/J\cong (A(J/I))/(J(J/I))=(J/I)/(J^2/I)$.

Comment: $J(J/I)=J^2/I=(J/I)^2$?

Comment: Yes. The first equality is from the A-module structure on $J/I$ and the second is from the definition of products of ideals of a quotient ring.

Comment: That is not correct. It should be $J(J/I) = (J^2 +I)/I$. It may happen that $J^2$ does not contain $I$, therefore $J^2/I$ doesn’t make sense.

Comment: For example, take the ring $R=\mathbb Z$ and the ideals $I=(6)$, $J=(2)$.